# General question about Power BI and SQL Server

Tags: dashboard, warehouse

We are in the process of creating a dashboard with Power BI.
We have two licenses of Power BI pro that we are using the create a dashboard with a SQL Server backend.
Can people share with me how they distributed the Power BI reports they developed to their users?  We have 600 people in the company and we don't want to have to buy 600 Power BI licenses.  Can you please give in detail the entire architecture you used to build your dashboard including the backend architecture?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are three options. I assume you've made some research and knows pros and cons of :

1. Power BI Report Server - which is a dedicated on-prem server
2. Power BI embeded - in MS Azure cloud
3. Publish on the web - hosted on Microsoft's website.

**Hosting** : I'd a similar requirement of sharing Power BI reports with about 200 users. And I am using Azure Power BI embedded solution which is quite flexible. The users don't need to purchase Power BI Pro license and we can schedule server switch on/off depending on day timings as well as on-demand. Several pricing plans are available.

**Architecture in brief** : We've custom application which connects to various systems such as SAP, several MS Excel files and a couple of .net based web apps. The custom application fetches the data, applies a bit of validation (esp cleansing) and puts the data in the SQL Server from where Power BI dashboards & reports are shown. The SQL Server DB is hosted in Azure.

We had an option of using Power BI Gateway connector but we discarded it.

We've 2 Power BI Pro licenses for the users who need to support/enhance the dashboards/reports.